# NdSolve problem :NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am new to Mathematica.
I am working on solving the following different equations numerically written in the code as below. Not so sure about the boundary values that depends on R (M(0)=0, n(1)=0) are sufficient to solve the following different equations. Also, I just put N0=4 for all the numerical integration to take places.

```
 Mneu = 1.877837359*10^3*(MeV/c^2); a = 1; kb = 1; 
  hbar = 1; c = 1; MeV = 1; N0 = 4; R0 = 4; 
m = 2*Mneu; 
\[Mu]0 = 4*Pi*hbar^2 * (a/m)*10^6; 


qnonrel = Flatten[Join[Table[D[n[i][M, R], R] == 
           -((G*M[i][n, R]*(2*m + \[Mu]0*n[i][M, R]))/
                (2*R^2*\[Mu]0)), {i, 1, N0}], 
       Table[D[M[i][n, R], R] == 4*Pi*R^2*
             (m*n[i][M, R] + (1/2)*\[Mu]0*n[i][M, R]^2), 
         {i, 1, N0}], {n[0][M, R0] == 0, M[0][n, 0] == 0, 
         n[R0][M, N0/2] == 0, M[0][n, N0/2] == 0}, 
       Table[n[i][M, R0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}], 
       Table[n[i][M, R0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}], 
       Table[M[i][n, 0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}], 
       Table[M[i][n, 0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}]]]

eqtwo = NDSolve[qnonrel, {Table[n[i], {i, 0, N0}], 
       Table[M[i], {i, 0, N0}]}, {R, 100}]
```

I have checked the similar problems online but it seemed that I couldn't find the root of problem. It must be something particular that I have missed.

Comment: what does `[Mu]0 = 4 [Pi] *hbar^2*a/m *10^(6)`  mean?  [Mu] times zero?  If you are used 2D math notations, you need to copy the code as input form from your cell and paste here. Otherwise, no one can read the above as is. These are the steps: Put all the code in one cell. Make a copy of the cell. Then select the cell and convert to inputForm. Then copy the result as text, then paste it here.

Comment: Hi Nasser, I just edited into Input Form as per request.  [Mu]0 = 4 [Pi] *hbar^2*a/m *10^(6) just an expression for defining constant [Mu]0 or miu.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues one can spot:

1. Some dependent variables are functions of `M` and `R`, some of `n` and `R`.
2. While `M` and `n` appear as independent variables in the equations, for example, `M[1][n, R]` and `n[1][M, R]`, they are not listed as integration variables.
3. You have initial conditions for `M[0]` and `n[0]` but no corresponding differential equation.
4. `M` and `n` appear both as independent variables and in the indexed heads, `M[0]`, `M[1]`,..., `n[0]`, `n[1]`,....

The first two are certainly problems.  The arguments to the functions must be the same.  If you need all three, then try to set up the system with functions of the form `f[n, M, R]`.  Or if `n` and `M` are indices, perhaps use functions of the form `M[n1, M1][R]`.

The last two issues may or may not be problems. The relationships between, for instance, `M[0]` and `M`, might cause some confusion inside `NDSolve`, if `M` is ever replaced by a numeric value.

It's impossible for me to fix these things myself as I cannot figure out what the intended equations are.  There may be other problems, depending on how the issues above are resolved.